# Using MS Word for editing a already published Blog in SharePoint 2010 Blog site

Tags: blog

I've seen that we can use MS Word to create new Blog posts.
The option is available under `Blog Tools > Launch blog program` to post

Works fine, word opens with Blog kind of template, and I can publish But after the blog article is published, how do I edit the blog post using word again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a blog post explaining how you can [edit existing posts with Word editor](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/steventap/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26).

Comment: Hi Toni! Looks like the link you provided is broken. Can you fix it and possibly extend your answer, since as of now this doesn't help much. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using Windows Live Writer (WLW) rather than Word for editing blog posts. Word is really overkill and not specifically designed for blogs like WLW is.

WLW is a free download from Microsoft:
http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer

Comment: Links is broken, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8621 contains a download that fails to install on windows 10

Comment: Note that my answer is from 2011. WLW was discontinued years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Using Word 2010

1. I went through the actions to create a new blog post to get to the Blog UI
2. Use the "open existing" command
3. Make edits and "publish" as usual

Comment: open existing only shows that last blog entries